# Azure: get notifiy when webrole down

Tags: azure, notifications

We have built our first azure web application. On february 29th the whole cloud went down (and can't be pinged) and it got us to think: is there a way for us to know when our web app is down and what made it go down?

If so, is there a way to get notified (email) of this, so we can put our web app back up?

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to the service dashboard RSS feed for your data center from:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/

That will let you know when Azure is having a problem.

For your application, one method would be to use Gomez:

http://www.gomeznetworks.com/

Another would be to use AzureOps:

http://www.opstera.com/products/product-tour

Comment: I wouldn't depend too much on the service dashboard, while it can be useful for getting updates on larger issues I think it is manually updated once MS acknowledges that there's an issue so it's not very timely.  Also if something is only affecting a small number of users, then it doesn't make it onto the dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

[Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/) has a free version (one website).
I've used it in the past and found it to be reliable.

Comment: Pingdom's monitoring is very lightweight. They didn't detect when my rest web service went down nor my website during the recent leap day azure crash.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tom !

Peter, You can use a 3rd party service for literally free like ours. The service performs routine health check, sends you role health information, tracks and aggregates performance data across multiple roles and instances and is your eyes and ears on Azure. Give it a spin at http://www.opstera.com/products/

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Copper Egg](http://www.copperegg.com/) and like it.  They also have a free version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a service currently in beta that performs cloud based monitoring for azure called [Cloudish](http://www.cloudish.net/). I just started using the service and everything was easy to setup and use. They take care of all the notifications you just specify when, why, and how you wish to be notified.

I think you can be notified by sms, email, http post, or service bus but i've only tested email and http post.